# Browsers won't load css/js files with https URL

Tags: safari, google-chrome, firefox, web-browsing

Firefox, Safari and Chrome won't load any CSS or JS files when I open an HTTPS url, for example on Twitter, it will only load the HTML.

When I look at firebug in Firefox I get the following errors:

[image: firebug error]

- Mac OS X version: 10.6.7
- And all my browsers are up to date.

Anyone any idea what it could be?

Comment: I've had this bug in Firefox (I don't use Chrome or Safari). I don't know what causes it, but for some reason clearing the cache fixes it for me.

Comment: @michaelmichael I tried and it didn't work :(

Comment: Clearing the cache worked for me as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My system date wasn't correct, it was set 2 months back. When I changed it to the date of today my problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought ... have you checked if you are using any custom Styles in those browsers? Alternatively for Safari make sure to check in the Develop menu if you have disabled styles or JS. Just to eliminate the possible culprits.

Comment: Nop never used custom styles for any browsers. And I checked if I disabled styles/js files but i didn't disabled them either.

Comment: OK, how about adblock? Are you using some kind of adblock on those browsers? Just looked at your posted screenshot and it seams that google analytic was also blocked. Maybe you are using some system-wide network filtering that you've forgot that you have?

Comment: +1 it was the Developer menu interfering with styles for me. "Reset Safari" should reset the developer menu too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in all the browsers. Clearing the cache solved this for me.